# Bash: running background job and getting pid

Tags: python, linux, bash, pid, paramiko

```
$1 &
echo $!
```

is there a different way to launch a command in the background and return the pid immediately?

So when I launch `bash run.sh "python worker.py"` it will give me the pid of the launched job.

I am using paramiko, a python library which doesn't work with `python worker.py &`. so I want to create a bash script which will do this for me on the remote server.

Comment: is there a different way to launch a command in the background and return the pid immediately?

Comment: When you do "bash run.sh" you aren't doing anything in the background - you are doing it in the foreground.

Comment: The way you have mentioned is the standard way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using bash, you can just get the list of background processes from `jobs`, and instruct it to return the PID via the `-l` flag. To quote `man bash`:

> ```
>    jobs [-lnprs] [ jobspec ... ]
>    jobs -x command [ args ... ]
>           The first form lists the active jobs.  The options have the
>           following meanings:
>           -l     List process IDs in addition to the normal information.
> ```

So in your case, something like 
`jobs -l | grep 'worker.py' | awk '{print $2}'` would probably give you what you want.